# Python shell not finding the file that is in the same folder (CSV)

Tags: python

I am new to python and am learning opening/reading a file using CSV.
In my folder I have a fruit.txt text file(notepad) and I am trying to open it on python shell using this code:

```
import csv

inFile = open("fruit.txt", "r")
```

and I get this error:

```
File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
inFile = open("fruit.txt", "r")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'fruit.txt'
```

I have both the text file and the program in the same folder; I don't know what the problem is.

[Here is the screenshot of my folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjgC4.png)

Thank you:)

Comment: How are you executing your script?

Comment: I am just clicking enter on IDLE (python 3.8 32-bit)

Answer (score 1):

Relative file paths are relative to your current working directory (the directory your terminal is open), not the file that is being executed. You can check your working directory with

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

Try moving your terminal's working directory to the scripts directory, then run the program.

Comment: I moved the folder python scripts that has fruit text to my working directory. Then I used     os.chdir('pythonScripts') to change the directory and I still get this error!!    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#21>", line 1, in <module>
    os.chdir('pythonScripts')
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'pythonScripts'

Comment: @Selina This error is saying the folder `pythonScripts` can not be found. You may already be in that folder.